If a Niblonian can erase Fry's memories but the Brains can't, does that mean the Niblonians are more powerful than the Brains?
In season 3 episode 7 "The Day the Earth Stood Stupid" and season 4 episode 10 "The Why of Fry," the Brains' psychic attacks have no effect on Fry, but at the end of The Why of Fry Nibbler was able to erase Fry's memories of the event. Does that mean the Niblonians are more powerful than the Brains?

Short answer, not really. Could be different contexts, different environments, different random factors...

If a person living by the beach can easily go for a walk and pick up a seashell, and I cannot, does that mean they are more powerful than me?

"More powerful" is not a well-defined concept, and generally answers to questions about are X more powerful than Y will tend to be opinion based.

Only the "more powerful" bit is really opinion based - If this question was restated as something like "Why can the Nibblonians erase Fry's memories when the Brains' psychic attacks had no effect on him?" it would be worth reopening, as well as the fact that @F1Krazy's answer would answer it.

Fry's immunity to the Brains' attacks is because he lacks the Delta brainwave, which the Brains used as their attack vector. The Nibblonians know Fry lacks this brain wave, and their memory-erasing ability is evidently not affected by him lacking it. So the Nibblonians aren't necessarily more powerful than the Brains, it's just that Fry has a neurological quirk that renders him immune to the latter but not the former.
